# Some confusion about Riemannian symmetric space

Tags: riemannian-geometry, lie-algebras, symmetric-spaces

Recently I'm learning some basic theories about symmetric spaces from "Differential geometry, Lie groups, and symmetric space" written by Sigurdur Helgason, and I have some confusion. I Hope someone can help me, and thanks in advance.

Suppose $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian symmetric, and $G$ is the identity component of the isometry group of $(M,g)$. Then for any $p\in M$, if we use $K$ to denote the isotropic group $G_p$, then $(G,K)$ gives a Riemannian symmetric pair. Here are some of my questions:

1. In the definition of Riemannian symmetric pair $(G,K)$, we request the Lie group $G$ to be connected, but why? Is there any advantage to doing this?
2. Is there only one way to realize a Riemannian symmetric space as a Riemannian symmetric pair? In other words, Do there exist two Riemannian symmetric pairs corresponding to the same Riemannian symmetric space?

---

On the other hand, any Riemannian symmetric gives an effective orthogonal symmetric Lie algebra $(\mathfrak{g},s)$ with Cartan decomposition $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{k}\oplus\mathfrak{p}$. The effectivity is define by $\mathfrak{z}\cap\mathfrak{k}=0$, where $\mathfrak{z}$ is the center of $\mathfrak{g}$. Some other authors also define it by $\mathfrak{k}$ having no nonzero idea of $\mathfrak{g}$. Here are some of my questions:

3. I cannot understand why "effective" is defined like these, and the relationship between these two definitions. I think it may be related to the action of $G$ on $G/K$ is effective, since some authors say "$\mathfrak{k}$ having no nonzero idea of $\mathfrak{g}$" if and only if $G$ acts on $G/K$ almost effectively (I'm not quite sure what is "almost effective", maybe only finite elements acts trivially).
4. Since any orthogonal symmetric Lie algebra coming from Riemannian symmetric space is effective, why don't we only consider effective ones?

---

Given a symmetric pair $(G,K)$ with Cartan decomposition $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{k}\oplus\mathfrak{m}$, we know that $K$ can act on $\mathfrak{m}$ via adjoint representation. On the other hand, $K$ can also act on $T_pM$ via isotropic representation, that is $k\mapsto (dL_k)_p$. My question is that

5. [This link](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Isotropy_representation) said that if we identify $T_pM\cong\mathfrak{m}$, we will see that the adjoint representation and isotropic representation are the same, but why?

Comment: 1. Well if you have a disconnected group $G$ you can just take the connected component of the identity and get the same symmetric space (obviously you are cutting out some isometries this way but you can now classify them more easily)

Comment: 2. The correspondence between symmetric spaces and symmetric decompositions/pairs is 1-to-1 up to isomorphism and taking covers. That is each Riemannian symmetric space has only 1 symmetric pair associated but its universal cover will also have the same pair.

Comment: @Callum So if $G$ is a disconnected group and $(G, K)$ is a Riemannian symmetric pair, then $(G_0, K_0)$ gives a Riemannian symmetric pair, which gives the same Riemannian symmetric space as $(G, K)$, so just for convenience we only consider Riemannian symmetric pair $(G, K)$ with $G$ connected.

Comment: @Callum and where can I find proof of my second question? Thanks a lot for your comments

Comment: Yes $G/K = G_0/K_0$ (obviously there is a technical difference as homogeneous spaces but the map is a $G_0$-equivariant diffeomorphism). As to the second point I realise I've slightly misread what you meant. What is true is that there is only 1 orthogonal symmetric Lie algebra (in the language of Helgason) corresponding to a given symmetric space but that symmetric spaces sharing a cover have the same orthogonal  symmetric Lie algebra (prop 3.6).

Comment: In terms of symmetric pairs, there is at least only one natural choice of symmetric pair $(G,K)$ for a symmetric space $M$ given by $G = I_0 (M)$ (the connected component of the identity in the isometry group) and $K$ the stabiliser of a point. I think you can create other connected $G$ that work by simply extending $G$ by elements that act trivially. I suspect that $G = I_0 (M)$ is the only choice that acts (almost?) effectively but I don't know.

Comment: Note we are now drifting into your 3rd point and yes I do believe that definition of effective ensures the group acts "almost effectively" (only elements of the centre act trivially and there are finitely many of these)

Comment: @Callum Thanks a lot, I'v found that if (G,K) is an orthogonal symmetric Lie algebra which gives a Riemannian symmetric space $(M,g)$. If $G$ acts on $M$ effective, then we must have $G$ is the identity component of the isometry group of $M$, and for Euclidean type there is a counterexample by considering $G=\mathbb{R}^n$ and $K=\{0\}$.

Comment: @Callum For third point, I also found the relationship between "effectivity" of orthogonal symmetric Lie algebra and almost effective action, and I'll list all things I learnt these days to give an answer of this question. Thanks again, and hope further discussion.